# Handling windows socket error

Tags: c++, sockets

I am retrieving data from the socket using the following code

```
iResult =  recv(Socket,data_array,sizeof(data_array),0);
```

Now the documentation states that if recv is succefull it would return the no. of bytes retrieved otherwise it would return an error code. How do I check for that error code. I mean what if the data retrieved is the same amount as the value of error code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740128%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get some more detail.

Basically, when an error occurs, `SOCKET_ERROR` (-1) gets returned, and you then have to call `WSAGetLastError()`, or read `errno` or other platform-specific equivalent, to get the specific error code.

Answer (score 3):

If the return value is negative (i.e. SOCKET_ERROR or -1), that's an error.

Answer (score 0):

> Now the documentation states that if recv is succefull it would return the no. of bytes retrieved otherwise it would return an error code.

No, it doesn't say that at all. Read it again. It says it returns the number of bytes transferred if successful, otherwise `-1`, with the error available in `errno,` or in Windows via `WSAGetLastError().`

> How do I check for that error code. I mean what if the data retrieved is the same amount as the value of error code.

You can't transfer -1 bytes. There is no ambiguity.